# How can I get RF MOSFET spice models?

Tags: mosfet, rf, simulation, spice, model

I am interested on design and simulate some input stage for a scope, and I want to play polarisation of a BF1105 but I cant get its SPICE model, similar happen with other UHF transistors.

how the manufaturers expect I can design using its parts?

Comment: You're expected to design with this transistor on a PCB. You DC-bias it such as you want it (see the datasheet) and then use a network analyzer to do the matching. A SPICE model would not help much as performance is mostly determined by PCB layout parasitics.

Comment: The datasheet has a test circuit with resonant sections. Work with those.